# HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in move upload file

Tags: php, file

I am trying to upload a file from local to server

i am getting this error 
**HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections**

i am using this code

```
$target_path="http://www.example.net/entities/"; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 

    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Is, there is any way to upload the files from local to server

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this idea that you can specify a full URL to the website's folder and upload stuff just like that?

Comment: i am trying to upload files from local

Comment: You have to provide server PATH instead of URL!

Comment: i dnt have server path ..

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `move_uploaded_file` with url / remote path e.g 'example.com/example/' try local path like './example/' it will cosider as 'example.com/example/

```
$target_path="./entities/";  // example.com/entities/
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path .$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])) { 

   echo 'uploaded';

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you try to upload file from local server to remote and your provided code is located in local server. Than it's not possible.

Use [`ftp_put()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) to upload file via FTP to remote server.

If your code is located in remote server (where you try to save file) than provide server path instead of url to that directory. To get path to that directory, simply create file there with code [`echo dirname(__FILE__)` (or `echo __DIR__` as of PHP >= 5.3.0)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to get server path of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your target path should be something like

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/entities/";
```

I hope this helps anyone coming here over this **HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections**